# Multiple versions of "JDK", which "java.exe" file to execute?

Tags: java

I have installed multiple versions of `JDK`, including `1.6`,`1.7`,`1.8`.

I want to know which version of `java.exe` gets executed when I run software that needs `JRE`. I did some testing, see below:

### Tests:

*cmd.exe command:* `echo %java_home%`
*prints:* `java version "1.8.0_31"`

---

*cmd.exe command:* `java -version`
*prints:* `java version "1.8.0_31"`

---

Then I checked the register table in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.8` and got the `javaHome` key value
*result:* `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31`.

---

*java code:* `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));`
*prints:* `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre`

---

Finally, I opened the task manager, searched the `java.exe` process and located the `java.exe` directory at:
*result:* `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin`

---

### Question:

I'm confused which `jave.exe` file the computer chooses. Can you help?

Comment: What is the value of your PATH environment variable? That is the one used to locate any executable, e.g. the java.exe binary.

Comment: Also, where are you running the Java code from? Your editor/IDE might also have a property that specifies which JRE it will use to execute your code.

Comment: Did you run your System.out-code inside an IDE (eclipse or something)?

Comment: do you "run the java code" in IDE?

Comment: command in dos `java -version` will check the `PATH` environment variable to find the `java.exe`, and find the `java.exe` file in `java1.8` install directory

Comment: check your PATH and JAVA_HOME env varibale and set them according to your need

Comment: How was the Java 1.7 JRE (as found from Task Manager) *launched*? If it was done from the command line it would have been the 1.8, as per the `java -version` reported. Otherwise, the program that launches the JRE (to run whichever class) is responsible and may be fixated on 1.7.. if it was launched as a result of running a JNLP/JWS (eg) file from Explorer, then that would have consulted the appropriate Shell Open registry configuration.

Comment: I got it ! my IDE project sdk is jdk 1.7 ! thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Passive approach

You may want what the `where` windows command line utility does; assuming you have only one java.exe in your `%PATH%`

Try:

```
where java.exe
```

If you have multiple version of java pin your %PATH% this will return multiple values. (unfortunately)

## Active approach

Set your environment this way:

Have your `PATH` environment variable to point **ONLY** to `c:\tools\java\default`

Store all your jre in one folder like

```
C:\tools\Java\JRE_1.6
C:\tools\Java\JRE_1.7
C:\tools\Java\JRE_1.8
```

Then open a comman propt and inside `C:\tools\Java\` execute

```
junction default JRE_1.6
```

This will create a [junction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) (wich is more or less like a symbolic lync).

In this way you will always have your default java in `c:\tools\java\default`.
If you then need to change your default java to the 1.8 version you just neet to execute

```
junction -d default
junction default JRE_1.8
```

Comment: the result is :                                                                                                       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\bin\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe and It seems that only jdk 1.8

Comment: This is because you have multiple version of java in your %PATH%. Unfortunately what you really need would be the windows equivalent of the linux which command, that does not exist, as far as I know. Many calims where is its equivalent, but there are differencies.

Answer (score 0):

From information you provided your default java is set to java 8 and the program you run is like to be run in some ide that use java 7.
Java -version command gives the default set java in your system.

Comment: I got it !My IDE project SDK is `jdk1.7` . But I want to know which `java.exe` would be execute if run a software that need `Jre`?

Comment: If the software configuration file does not have specified any jre then jre of default jdk will run..

Comment: But how can I know which jdk is the defalut jdk?